# M1 - Efficient Bulk Update Order Attribute

Tags: orders, magento-1, performance

## The problem

I have added a custom attribute to the `sales_flat_order` table like:

```
/* @var $installer Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup */
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup('setup');

$installer->addAttribute(
    Mage_Sales_Model_Order::ENTITY,
    'new_attribute_code',
    array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'visible' => true,
    )
);
```

I would like to programmatically do a bulk update of orders to set a new value for this attribute against many orders. This value will be scripted to update based on the result of another system, it's not a "one off" or solved by having a default value.

I hoped Magento would have a similar kind of interface as it does for products which allows for bulk updates like

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
    $productIdsArray,
    array('description' => 'New desc'),
    Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID
);
```

However, I can find no such interface. Does anyone know an efficient and safe way to bulk update orders?

## Research

### Product bulk update

The product bulk update seems to boil down to `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract::_saveAttributeValue`. This won't help me for `Mage_Sales` entities. I could however use it as inspiration for a direct sql level access. However this is something I would hope Magento handles.

### Order bulk cancel

I know that you can mark many orders as "cancelled" through the mass action in the magento admin panel. However under the hood it is in fact doing

```
public function massCancelAction()
{
    $orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids', array());

    foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        if ($order->canCancel()) {
            $order->cancel()
                ->save();
        }
    }
```

That is pretty grim. It's not even loading all the orders in a collection before trying to cancel. It's calling `load` within a for loop. Ew.

Does anyone know of anything clever I can be doing here?

### Responses

@Raphael thanks for your answer. Popping this in my entities' resource model seemed to work okay.

```
private function getOrderTable()
{
    return $this->getTable('sales/order');
}

public function updateOrders(array $orderIds, $value)
{
    if (empty($orderIds) || !is_string($value)) {
        return $this;
    }

    $adapter = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
    try {
        $adapter->beginTransaction();

        $data  = array(
            'new_attribute_code' => $value,
        );

        $condition = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteInto($this->getIdFieldName() . ' IN(?)', $orderIds);
        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->update($this->getOrderTable(), $data, $condition);

        $adapter->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $adapter->rollBack();
        throw $e;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the problem a while ago with quote attributes.

The solution I came up with was implementing a `saveAttribute` method on the resource class which accepts an array of attributes to update:

```
public function saveAttribute($model, $attributes)
{
    try {
        $adapter = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
        $adapter->beginTransaction();
        $condition = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteInto($this->getIdFieldName() . '=?', $model->getId());
        $data      = array();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            $value = $model->getData($attribute);
            if (isset($value)) {
                $data[$attribute] = $value;
            }
        }
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $this->_getWriteAdapter()->update($this->getMainTable(), $data, $condition);
        }
        $adapter->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $adapter->rollBack();
        throw $e;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Thus in my collection loop I was able to do:

```
foreach ($orders as $order)
{
    $order->setMyAttribute($value);
    $order->getResource()->saveAttribute($order,array('my_attribute'));
}
```

I never actually pushed my research further to find out if Magento had something close to this to handle bulk attributes update differently.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was a helpful starting point! See my updated question :)