# Magento 1 - Save Collection Without Foreach

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, php-5.4, save

I am currently going through and optimizing our codebase for our custom modules. I am using [PHP Codesniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/) along with the [Magento Coding Standard](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard) rules to scan our code.

In many of our files I see a warning like

```
Model LSD method save() detected in loop
```

Here is an example of a function containing that error

```
public function resetmasstatusAction()
 {
    $invoicesIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('invoice_ids');
    if (!empty($invoicesIds)) {
        $invoices = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_invoice_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $invoicesIds))
            ->load();
        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) :
            $invoice->setMas_status('NEW')
                ->setMas_updated_at(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                ->save();
        endforeach;
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/sales_invoice/index');
}
```

How would I go about doing the save operation for all items in a collection such as this one, without having the `save()` function in the `foreach` loop to improve performance?

Comment: I guess no one had an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [M1 - Efficient Bulk Update Order Attribute](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110131/m1-efficient-bulk-update-order-attribute)

Comment: please check the method the OP created in his question (my answer actually includes a foreach, but the OP created his own method which does not)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism, I actually determined how to do this and am posting my answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research into this, I discovered that the best way to do this is like the following.

Please note that the walk iterator is essentially the same thing as a foreach loop, however the goal in my original question was how to not run a SQL query over and over again in a foreach loop.

By running the save() function on the entire $invoices object, we essentially run a large SQL query to save all of the rows at once rather than running a bunch of small queries.

```
public function resetmasstatusAction()
 {
    $invoicesIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('invoice_ids');
    if (!empty($invoicesIds)) {
        $invoices = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_invoice_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $invoicesIds))
            ->load();
        //The below will allow you to save the updated collection
        //Without running multiple SQL queries in the foreach loop.
        $invoices->walk('setMas_status', array('NEW');
        $invoices->walk('setMas_updated_at', array(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));           
        $invoices->save();
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/sales_invoice/index');
}
```

Comment: The `save` method from the 'sales/order_invoice_collection' is defined in `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract`, where it actually does a foreach to save each item.